# md-toolbar primary color not shown

Tags: angular-material2

Hello Stack community.

Im using md-toolbar in this simple example component

https://github.com/oddskill/angularmaterial2template/blob/master/src/app/frame/base/base.component.html

The theme file is included in styles.css file 
https://github.com/oddskill/angularmaterial2template/blob/master/src/styles.css

Any idea why the toolbar color is not showing up ?

best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the `MdToolbarModule` in your `frame.module.ts`file:

```
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
    ..., 
    MdToolbarModule
],
```